# children name with adbul or we can name without abdul with Allah name

Tags: children, naming, asma-ul-husna, baby

asslam o alaikum

***Allah blessed me a baby boy i want to name MoizBari or we should add Abdul is mandatory to add

Comment: Why mandatory? your name have no Abdul Allah? from where you get that Muslims should all be Abdul Allah?

Answer (score 0):

Brother, adding Abdur or Abdul is must when you are keeping a name of Allah which only belongs to Allah. For example Kuddus, Khaliq, Rahman etc. You must add Abdur before these names.

There are other names of Allah which can be used to human. For example Ar-Rahim. You can name your child Rahim only by removing the prefix.

If you want to use Allah's unique names you have to add Abdur or Abdul in this case. Jazakallah Khairan